# There are no slides to show. So the carousel won't be re-rendered ngx-owl-carousel console message

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I am trying to use `ngx-owl-carousel-o` in my angular 11 application but I get the following message in my console:

> There are no slides to show. So the carousel won't be re-rendered

and nothing shows in the place where the carousel is supposed to be.

I have this version installed:

```
"ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^6.0.2",
```

and this is my html:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="slides.length > 0">
    <owl-carousel-o [options]="owlCarouselCustomOptions">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides">
        <ng-template carouselSlide [id]="slide.id">
          <img [src]="slide.img" />
        </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
    </owl-carousel-o>
  </ng-container>
```

This is the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
})
export class Page implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  owlCarouselCustomOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    pullDrag: false,
    dots: false,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ['', ''],
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      400: {
        items: 2,
      },
      740: {
        items: 3,
      },
      940: {
        items: 4,
      },
    },
    nav: true,
  };

  slides = [
    { id: 1, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/423b42/fff' },
    { id: 2, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/2a2b7a/fff' },
    { id: 3, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/1a2b7a/fff' },
    { id: 4, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/7a2b7a/fff' },
    { id: 5, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/9a2b7a/fff' },
    { id: 6, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/5a2b7a/fff' },
    { id: 6, img: 'https://dummyimage.com/350x150/4a2b7a/fff' },
  ];
}
```

Comment: I'm having the similar problem when rendering. Please post the solution in anyone is able to help

Answer (score 0):

For angular 11, you need to install ngx-owl-carousel version 5.x.x.
For installing: `npm i ngx-owl-carousel@5.1.1`
[image]